# Convergence of sequence of $L^{p}$ function

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, lp-spaces

Given that $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is bounded. If you are given that $u_{k} \rightarrow u$ in $L^{p- \epsilon}(\Omega)$ and a functions $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ where $\{f(u_{k})\}_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ is bounded in $L^{p'+\epsilon}(\Omega)$, where $\epsilon > 0$ and $p' = \frac{p}{p-1}$. How does it follow that $$\int_{\Omega}f(u_{k})(u_{k}-u)dx \rightarrow 0$$
Given that $p-\epsilon > 1$ annd $p'+ \epsilon > 1$. Can anyone see how this follows?

Comment: Do you really mean $f(u_k)$?

Comment: @Etienne I corrected the question now.

Comment: OK, but the the domain of $f$ should be $\mathbb R$, not $\Omega$

Comment: Is $\Omega$ a bounded set?

Comment: I too would like $\Omega$ to be bounded but even then I am skeptical.  I think $(p - \epsilon)' > p'+\epsilon$ so that does not even seem to be enough.  What is the origin of this problem?  Are there any extra details to $u$ and $f$ or are they totally general?

Comment: @NemisL. Yes $\Omega$ is bounded.

Comment: @JasonKnapp The problem is from a book 'nonlinear partial differential equations with applications'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$p'$ is the conjugate exponent of $p$. Let $(p-\epsilon)'$ be the conjugate exponent of $p-\epsilon$. Then
$$
(p-\epsilon)'=p'+\frac{\epsilon}{(p-1-\epsilon)(p-1)}=p'+\delta,\quad\delta>0.
$$
Then, by Hölder's inequality:
$$
\Bigl|\int_{\Omega}f(u_{k})\,(u_{k}-u)\,dx\Bigr|\le\Bigl(\int_{\Omega}|f(u_{k})|^{p'+\delta}\,dx\Bigr)^{1/(p'+\delta)}\Bigl(\int_{\Omega}|u_k-u|^{p-\epsilon}\,dx\Bigr)^{1/(p-\epsilon)}.
$$
This gives the result if $\Omega$ is bounded and $\delta\le\epsilon$, or for any $\Omega$ if the conditions are in the sense that they hold for all sufficiently small $\epsilon$.

Comment: Thanks for your response. So your $\delta$ is a function of $\epsilon$. But is there a way to guarantee that $\delta \leq \epsilon$. It doesn't seem that choosing $\epsilon$ sufficiently small would necessarily ensure that $\delta \leq \epsilon$? Also, have you studied 'nonlinear partial differential equations with applications' by Roubicek by any chance? My question was inspired by a proof in this book.

Comment: You would use two different $\epsilon$'s. Choose first $\epsilon_1$ such that $u_k\to u$ in $L^{p-\epsilon_1}$. Now choose a smaller $\epsilon_2$ so that the corresponding $\delta$ is smaller than $\epsilon_1$. And no, I do not know that book by Roubicek.

Comment: Okay I see but I need one $\epsilon$ only (not two) such that the result holds as stated in my original question. Using your argument above, having looked at it again it does seem that as $\delta$ decreases as $\epsilon$ gets smaller, could I not just use that argument directly and just state that $\epsilon$ is chosen small enough so that $\delta \leq \epsilon$ and then use the Holders Inequality as you did?

Comment: I am confused now.  Take for example $p = 2$.  As $\epsilon \to 1$, $(p-\epsilon)' \to \infty$ so in fact shrinking $\epsilon$ is counterproductive for ensuring smallness of $\delta$.

Comment: @JasonKnapp Why would you take $\epsilon \rightarrow 1$ for shrinking $\epsilon$? Take $\epsilon \in (0,1]$.

Comment: Right, that was silly :)

Comment: @JuliánAguirre Actually I see your point, you need two $\epsilon$'s as stated, since $\epsilon \leq \frac{\epsilon}{(p-1-\epsilon)(p-1)}$ for $\epsilon > 0$. We consider $u_{k} \rightarrow u$ in $L^{p - \epsilon}$ then there exists an $\epsilon_{\delta}$ where $\delta := \frac{\epsilon_{\delta}}{(p-1-\epsilon_{\delta})(p-1)}$ gives $\delta \leq \epsilon$ and $p' + \delta \leq p' + \epsilon$. If follows then that $u_{k} \rightarrow u$ in $L^{(p'-\epsilon_{\delta})}$ and $\{f(u_{k})\}_{k}$ is bounded in $L^{p' + \epsilon_{\delta}}$. Using Holders inequality the desired result follows.

Comment: @JuliánAguirre Do you think this proof is fine?

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant.

Comment: @JuliánAguirre The reasoning doesn't quite work the way I stated, problem is that you end up with two different $\epsilon$'s. Do you think this problem can be resolved with one $\epsilon$ which gives you the desired result?